Convergence of series from inverse of Cauchy product
The Cauchy product of two real or complex infinite series $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} a_n$ and $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} b_n$ is defined as:
$$ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}, c_n = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k} $$
Mertens' theorem states that if one of the two series $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} a_n$ and $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} b_n$ is absolutely convergent then the series $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} c_n$ also converge. If both $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} a_n$ and $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} b_n$ are absolutely convergent then $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} c_n$ is also absolutely convergent.
Now that we have two convergent series $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} a_n$ and $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} b_n$, when $b_0\neq 0$, by recursively defining $c_n$ as:
$$ c_n = \frac{a_n - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} c_k b_{n-k}}{b_0}, $$
we can make a series that satisfies:
$$ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}, a_n = \sum_{k=0}^n c_k b_{n-k}. $$
which resembles the inverse of a Cauchy product.
My question is: what's the condition on the series $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} a_n$ and $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} b_n$ for thus defined series $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} c_n$ to be convergent? Absolutely convergent?

unfortunately, your problem has no neat answer in terms that depend only on some generic property of $b_n$ as if even $a_n, b_n$ are very small or even if $a_n,b_n$ are nonzero only for finitely many $n$, it may turn out that $c_n$ can be large; if $\sum |b_n| < \infty$ AND if $\sum b_nz^n$ has no zeroes in the closed unit disc, then Wiener (and Mertens) Theorems guarantee that $\sum c_n$ converges if $\sum a_n$ does so and absolutely if the latter converges absolutely; in particular one sufficient condition is that $|b_0| > \sum_{n \ge 1}|b_n|$ but that is quite restrictive

@Conrad thanks for the comment. Have you seen this been discussed anywhere in the lectures or the articles? Looking for refs or useful keywords.

not that I know in these terms since it all depends on the unit disc zero set of the analytic function $\sum b_n z^n$ (which is defined there by the convergence of $\sum b_n$) and it is a notoriously difficult problem to say anything about that just from the coefficients $b_n$ (except of course in very specific cases)

It's natural to consider the associated entire series:
$$
\begin{align}
A(z) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n & B(z) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nz^n & C(z) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nz^n
\end{align}
$$
Your inverse Cauchy product is related to the usual inverse:
$$
C = \frac AB
$$
One simple approach to revert to Mertens' theorem consider $\sum \tilde b_n$ defined by the entire series:
$$
\frac1B = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \tilde b_nz^n
$$
You can now apply Mertens' theorem on $a,\tilde b,c$, since $c$ is a Cauchy product of $a,\tilde b$. Explicitly:
$$
\begin{align}
\tilde b_0 &= \frac1{b_0}\\
\tilde b_n &= -\frac1{b_0}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\tilde b_kb_{n-k} & n&>0
\end{align}
$$
You just need to characterise the convergence/absolute convergence of $\sum b_n$ using the properties of $\sum\tilde b_n$. The issue is that just information on the convergence of $\sum b_n$ is not enough as this simple example illustrates:
$$
\begin{align}
B &= 1-2z & b &= (1,-2,0, ...) \\
\frac1B &= \frac1{1-2z} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (2z)^n & \tilde b &= (2^n)_{n\geq0}
\end{align}
$$
The trouble is to locate the zeros of $B$. A necessary condition for the convergence of $\sum \tilde b_n$ is that $B$ must be zero free on the open unit disk. A sufficient condition for the absolute convergence of $\sum \tilde b_n$ is that $B$ must be zero free on a disk centred at the origin with radius greater than $1$.
Btw, for the final convergence of $\sum c_n$, you can strengthen the previous approach by noticing that a zero of $B$ can be cancelled by a zero of $A$. Therefore a necessary condition for the convergence of $\sum c_n$ is that in the open unit disk, the zeros of $B$ are also zeros of $A$ of at least the same order. A sufficient condition is the same on a disk of radius larger than $1$.
Hope this helps.

thx this is really helpful.
